# Android UI Test on SettingsApi popup

Tags: android, robotium, android-espresso

I wanna test whether the `"location setting dialog"` has been shown on display.

However I can not check whether it is a dialog or a dialog-like `Activity`.

I'm using now `Solo` and `Espresso` testing `utils`.

Is there someone that can give that a test and can know that `"location setting dialog"` is being shown on device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use solo(robotium) to solve the problem.
[C.](http://blog.egorand.me/testing-runtime-permissions-lessons-learned/)